# How to insert anti forgery token with Clojure Enlive

Tags: clojure, antiforgerytoken, enlive

I try to insert anti forgery token using ring.util.anti-forgery into html form:

```
(html/defsnippet post-edit-form "templates/blog.html" [:.post-edit]
   []
   [:form] (html/after (html/html-content (anti-forgery-field))))
```

Get exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Don't know how to create ISeq from: net.cgrand.enlive_html$html_content$fn__5571
RT.java:505 clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom
RT.java:486 clojure.lang.RT.seq
core.clj:133    clojure.core/seq
enlive_html.clj:227 net.cgrand.enlive-html/flatten-nodes-coll[fn]
enlive_html.clj:232 net.cgrand.enlive-html/flatten-nodes-coll[fn]
LazySeq.java:40 clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval
...
```

Also tried this:

```
(html/defsnippet post-edit-form "templates/blog.html" [:.post-edit]
  []
  [:form] (html/after (html/html [:input {:id "__anti-forgery-token"
                                          :name "__anti-forgery-token"
                                          :type "hidden"
                                          :value *anti-forgery-token*}])))
```

does not work :(

(anti-forgery-field) produces just html string with one 'input'. But i cant insert it into form.

Answer (score 3):

Done it!

Need to use html-snippet instead of html-content:

```
(html/defsnippet post-edit-form "templates/blog.html" [:.post-edit]
  []
  [:form] (html/append (html/html-snippet (anti-forgery-field))))
```